# ¿Problema al generar PDF con DOMPDF?

Tags: php

Saludos, al momento de generar mi reporte con DOMPDF miren lo que me arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me genera una pagina en blanco con mis datos en la manera en que esta en la imagen y con este error al final de la pagina:

Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent

Alguien sabe que pueda estar pasando? Dejare el codigo que utilizo:

```
 <?php
 require('../lib/conexion.php');
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <style media="screen">
 body{
 margin: 20px;
 }
 img{
 width: 150px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 75%;
 top: 0;
 }
 .head{
 position: absolute;
 left: 65%;
 top: 14%;
 background: #B40431;
 color: #fff;
 }
 h2,h3,h5{
 font-weight: bold;
 }
 </style>
 <?php
 $e = "SELECT * FROM empresa";
 $s = $mysqli->query($e);
 $r = $s -> fetch_assoc();
 ?>
 <body><br>
 <img src="../imgs/<?php echo $r['logo'];?>">
 <h5 style="margin-left:45px;"><?php echo $r['tipo']?></h5>
 <h5><?php echo $r['name']?></h5>
 <h6 style="margin-left:45px">Calle Merida con Av. Libertad Edificio Don 
 Rosario Piso 1 Locales 1 y 2</h6>
 <h6 style="margin-left:125px;">Barinas Estado Barinas - Venezuela</h6>
 <table class="head" width="250px" border="none">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>FECHA:</th>
      <th><?php echo date('d-m-Y')?></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
 <center>
  <h5>CIERRE DE CAJA DEL DIA: <?php echo date('d-m-Y')?> HASTA LAS <?php 
 echo date('h:i:s')?></h5>
 </center>
 <table  width="100%" border="none">
  <thead style="background:#B40431">
    <tr>
      <th>NRO</th>
      <th><center>CONCEPTO</center></th>
      <th>MONTO Bs.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 <?php
  $hoy = date('d-m-Y');
  $query = "SELECT id,concepto,monto FROM ingresos WHERE fecha = '$hoy'";
  $sql = $mysqli->query($query);
  if($sql->num_rows >0){
    $ingresos = 0;
  while($row = $sql -> fetch_assoc()){
    $ingresos += intval($row['monto'])
 ?>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['concepto']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['monto']?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 <?php }
  ?>
 <?php } else {
    $ingresos = 0;
  }
  ?>
  </table><br><br>

  <?php
  $egresos = "SELECT monto FROM egresos WHERE fecha = '$hoy'";
  $sql2 = $mysqli->query($egresos);
  if($sql2->num_rows>0){
  $t_egresos = 0;
  while($row2 = $sql2->fetch_assoc()){
  $t_egresos += intval($row2['monto']);
  }
  }else{
  $t_egresos = 0;
  }
  ?>
  <table width="100%" border="none">
  <thead style="background:#01A9DB">
    <tr>
      <th>TOTAL INGRESOS: </th>
      <th><center><?php echo $ingresos; ?> Bs.</center></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
  <?php $total = $ingresos - $t_egresos; ?>
      <td style="background:#0404B4; color:#fff">TOTAL EGRESOS: </td>
      <td style="background:#0404B4; color:#fff"><center><?php echo 
  $t_egresos; ?> Bs.</center></td>
    </tr>
    <th style="background:#01A9DB;">SALDO ACTUAL EN CAJA DEL DIA <?php echo 
  $hoy; ?> HASTA LAS <?php echo date('h:i:s') ?></th>
    <th style="background:#01A9DB;"><center><?php echo $total; ?> Bs.
  </center></th>
  </tbody>
  </table><br>

<span style="margin-left:60%">INGRESO</span>            <span style="margin-
left:5%"><?php echo $ingresos; ?> Bs.</span>
<span style="margin-left:60%">EGRESO</span>             <span style="margin-
left:5%"><?php echo $t_egresos; ?> Bs.</span>
<span style="margin-left:60%">PUNTO</span>
<span style="margin-left:60%">TRANSFERENCIA</span>
<span style="margin-left:60%">EFECTIVO</span>
<span style="margin-left:60%">DEVOLUCIÓN</span>

</body>
<?php
require_once '../dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper("A4", "letter");
$dompdf->loadHtml(ob_get_clean());
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$nombre_archivo = 'comprobante.pdf';
$dompdf->stream($nombre_archivo,array("Attachment"=>0));
?>
</html>
```

Comment: estas usando algun framework? como codeigniter por ejemplo?

Comment: ninguno julio. PHP puro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto suele ocurrir porque en algún lugar de su código se esta generando un espacio en blanco o una nueva linea.

Es probable que algún resultado de BD venga con el espacio en blanco o nueva linea.

Usa este código antes del `stream` para que vayas descartando:

```
$f;
$l;
if(headers_sent($f,$l)){
    echo $f,'<br/>',$l,'<br/>';
    die('se detecto linea');
}
```

Si no detecta sube el código unas lineas más hasta ubicarlo.

Comment: Julio me ha salido, se detecto linea 75. Que me dice esto? Ya borre los espacios de los span

Comment: En esa linea se esta enviando una cabecera que ocasiona el error, no se que linea sea exactamente la 75 en tu codigo porque tienes `require`, prueba primero comentando donde se muestra el error, reemplazalo por un valor en duro: <span style="margin-left:60%">INGRESO</span>            <span style="margin-
left:5%">1000 Bs.</span>

Comment: he borrado los span de la linea 75, y ahora tengo esto en la linea 112 <th style="background:#01A9DB;"><?php echo $total;?></th> no veo que afecte alli

Comment: revisa esas lineas en `conexion.php` revisa tambien que no se incluyan `header`

Comment: Ya he solucionado, jamas pense que los textos dentro de las etiquetas fueran a afectar con DOMPDF. pero bueno se quedara como lo deje. Gracias julio.

Comment: Exactamente que fue? que textos?

Comment: En la parte en donde tengo SALDO ACTUAL EN CAJA DEL DIA X HASTA LA HORA X, esa parte la he eliminado y los span de la parte de abajo. No me gusta asi pero que mas, he intentado metiendo esos texto en variables y imprimiendolas y igual pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Me han vuelto a salir otras lineas, y elimino texto y sigue. Mas problemas de lo que deberia genera esto! :(

Comment: No debería ser la solución, deberías descartar poniendo todo esa parte en duro nada de php y vayas reemplazando de a pocos.

Comment: Eso hare Julio, pero ya mañana, estoy un poco cansado! Gracias por tu ayuda. Por lo menos ya se que es por eso! Agradecido.

Comment: Tu código debería funcionar aun estando con la función que te di. Si esa funcion manda el mensaje es porque en algun lugar se esta enviando el header antes del DOMPDF

Comment: Revisa el archivo conexion.php. Suerte

Answer (score 1):

como dice juliocpiro.
con esta funcion, encontraras los espacios o header q te dan el problema.

```
$f;
$l;
if(headers_sent($f,$l)){
    echo $f,'<br/>',$l,'<br/>';
    die('se detecto linea');
}
```

en mi caso el espacio en blanco me generaba en el archivo donde esta mi conexion a mi bd.